# Where do I find absolute beginner's help on how to use Ubuntu preinstalled on my notebook?

Tags: installation, internet

I purchased a HP Elite notebook 2730 with an Ubuntu operating system on Ebay. I've never used Ubuntu before, and have to admit I'm only used Windows 7 before and not real computer literate. I'd like to access the internet, google and Facebook.  Not sure how to even turn it on. Can you please help me to use my HP elite notebook with Ubuntu?

Answer (score -1):

Hi there and welcome to the Ubuntu community!

You can read this [absolute beginners guide](http://www.makeuseof.com/pages/ubuntu-an-absolute-beginners-guide#chapter-6) to help you out. It covers all the essential parts to get you started.